# Sobipro component respond with a blank page

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-extensions, sobipro

I update Joomla to the most recent version (3.7.1).

Also update the Joomla component SobriPro to the most recent version (1.3.7).
Before the updates all works fine, after the updates the SobriPro component always responds with an empty page. Accessing SobiPro client or administration pages always retune a blank html page.

I already consult the administration and client Joomla error logs but nothing is register. I also try to run Joomla in debug mode but not getting any message.
Sure I run the updates first in a local dev environment.

In the local server all runs OK, I only have problems in the production environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem. In my production environment dosen’t have the Phar extension available.

The difficult to detect this limitation was because the sobi component return black pages without reporting any error.

To correct the problem I just uncompressed the sobi framework file and make a change in the sobi component loader code. This change is documented here: https://github.com/Sigsiu-NET/SobiPro/pull/8